# Magento 2 - Add attribute to script added with "text/x-magento-init"

Tags: magento2, javascript, script

Magento adds this google analytics script:

*vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/view/frontend/web/js/google-analytics.js*

It is getting initialised / loaded here:

*vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/view/frontend/templates/ga.phtml*

```
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_GoogleAnalytics/js/google-analytics": {
            "isCookieRestrictionModeEnabled": <?= (int)$block->isCookieRestrictionModeEnabled() ?>,
            "currentWebsite": <?= (int)$block->getCurrentWebsiteId() ?>,
            "cookieName": "<?= /* @noEscape */ \Magento\Cookie\Helper\Cookie::IS_USER_ALLOWED_SAVE_COOKIE ?>",
            "ordersTrackingData": <?= /* @noEscape */ json_encode($block->getOrdersTrackingData()) ?>,
            "pageTrackingData": <?= /* @noEscape */ json_encode($block->getPageTrackingData($accountId)) ?>
        }
    }
}
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
```

I need to add this tag: `type="text/plain"` and `data-cookieconsent="statistics"`

But the **type** is already `text/x-magento-init`, so how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to use the type="text/plain" ??

Comment: Because I need to. It is a requirement of the cookie consent tool.

Comment: By default the js/google-analytics restrict itself by a config config.isCookieRestrictionModeEnabled and run the script by allowedCookies = $.mage.cookies.get(config.cookieName);

Comment: Thus, you no need to update the script's type value

Comment: You just need to add a cookie which named user_allowed_save_cookie, and value is your website id. 

cookie['user_allowed_save_cookie'] = '{$websiteId: 1}';

Comment: This would allow all cookies. I need to be able to allow certain cookies e.g. statistic ones.